# How can I make an adaptive width for the X-axis in AmCharts 5

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, amcharts, x-axis

How can I make an adaptive width for the X-axis, so that when I shrink the screen, the columns with X-axis values are not deleted.

[Here is my chart](https://codepen.io/zxnarsgn-the-encoder/pen/BaMymeL)

Right now, if I compress the screen width, the columns get smaller and smaller and there is an offset that I don't understand how to adjust.

I want the number of X-axis columns to remain the same when compressing the screen width

I found [one example](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/vYamBNd) where the width of the grid is adjusted with the parameter

`baseInterval: { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 }`
but I don't understand how to integrate this into my code

Any ideas how to fix this?